# how to compare today date and input date in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have created a stage scaffold that has field planned start date and planned end date. now i want to run a loop that will check today date and compare it with planned end date. if date of today is greater than planned end date then it should increment the counter. how can i run such loop in rails model,view or in controller? here is view code--

show.html.erb

```
  <td class="text-bold"><%= stage.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
 <td class="text-bold"><%= stage.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes({stages: {tasks: {sub_tasks: {sub_sub_tasks: :sub_three_tasks}}}}).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages

  end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this in the controller?

```
counter = 0
@stages.each{|s| counter += 1 if s.planned_end_date.past?}
```

[.past? method source](https://apidock.com/rails/Date/past%3F)

Comment: counter gets printed 0.

Comment: That means no date is in the past.

Comment: here the problem is each stage has task that has many to one realtion with stage now also in show#action i want to calculate same for task ```@tasks.each{|s| counter += 1 if s.planned_end_date.past?}``` but i get undefined each method

Comment: @tasks is not a collection or array.